# How to take input file from terminal for python script?

Tags: python

I have a python script which uses a text file and manipulate the data from the file and output to another file. Basically I want it to work for any text file input. Right now I readline from the file and then print the output to screen. I want the output in a file.

So user can type the following and test for any file:

```
cat input_file.txt | python script.py > output_file.txt.
```

How can I implement this in my script? Thank You.

cat is command in linux. I don't know how it works.

Comment: Using `cat foo | bar` is never necessary; you can always just do `bar < foo` instead.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to call the input and output files as arguments for the python script:

```
import sys
inFile = sys.argv[1]
outFile = sys.argv[2]
```

Then you can read in all your data, do your manipulations, and write out the results:

```
with open(inFile,'r') as i:
    lines = i.readlines()

processedLines = manipulateData(lines)

with open(outFile,'w') as o:
    for line in processedLines:
        o.write(line)
```

You can call this program by running `python script.py input_file.txt output_file.txt`

If you absolutely must pipe the data to python (which is really not recommended), use `sys.stdin.readlines()`

Comment: Why is piping not recommended? (Or do you mean to say `cat foo | python bar.py` and `python bar.py < foo` are more complex than reading a file with `sys.arg[1]`?). `fileinput.input(sys.argv[1])` from the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/fileinput.html) module seems to cover both cases nicely.

Answer (score 10):

This method (your question) describes reading data from STDIN:

`cat input_file.txt | python script.py`

Solution: `script.py`:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

---

The method in above solutions describes taking argument parameters with your python call:

`python script.py input_file.txt`

Solution: `script.py`:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

```
cat input_file.txt | python script.py > output_file.txt.
```

You can passing a big string that has all the data inside input_file.txt instead of an actual file so in order to implement your python script, just take that it as a string argument and split the strings by new line characters, for example you can use "\n" as a delimiter to split that big string and to write to an outputfile, just do it in the normal way

i.e. `open file`, `write to the file` and `close file`

Comment: 'in windows you can use "\n" as a delimiter' is pretty misleading. On every modern platform _except_ Windows you can use `\n` as a delimiter. On Windows, you have to use `\r\n`, unless you use text mode with universal newlines, in which case Python lets you treat Windows like another platform.

Answer (score 1):

Sending output to a file is very similar to taking input from a file.

You open a file for writing the same way you do for reading, except with a `'w'` mode instead of an `'r'` mode.

You write to a file by calling `write` on it the same way you read by calling `read` or `readline`.

This is all explained in the [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) section of the tutorial.

So, if your existing code looks like this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line)
```

You just need to do this:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    while True:
        line = fin.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        fout.write(line)
```

---

If you're looking to allow the user to pass the filenames on the command line, use [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to get the filenames, or use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) for more complicated command-line argument parsing.

For example, you can change the first line to this:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin, open(sys.argv[2], 'w') as fout:
```

Now, you can run the program like this:

```
python script.py input_file.txt outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat input_file.txt | python script.py > output_file.txt
```

Basically, python script needs to read the input file and write to the standard output.

```
import sys
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version

```
python test.py < in.txt
```

Comment: The question is about how to make this work in Python, not how to send the file to the script’s stdin.